# Forwarding directories with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've looked through many questions on here but haven't found one that quite answers my question (could be wrong, feel free to suggest an answer I missed)
How would you write the .htaccess file to send all requests from the folder
`example.com/subpage/img` to `example.com/img` and `example.com/subpage/js` to `example.com/js`
Where subpage can be any text string
This is the file so far

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (^[A-Za-z]+[\/]?) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Secondly, how could you add a second parameter to the last rule? like `index.php?page=$1subpage=$2`
Please let me know if this needs to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to your existing code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/((?:img|js)/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(?:/([a-z]+))?/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Could you answer the second part?

Comment: Try to explain 2nd part better, where is 2nd part in captured string?

Comment: This isn't quite working, think its because the rule above is cutting off everything after /subpage
example.com/subpage/getscutoff

Comment: The second part would be like
`example.com/subpage/extrastuffhere`
So just adding another slash

Comment: Yes that's correct, my suggested rule should appear before your rule. Also I believe `/img` and `/js` are real directories?

Comment: Yes those are real directories, but could you write it so that instead of redirecting it just pulls it from the correct folder server side, and change the last rule so that the second parameter is optional instead of required?

Comment: Ok check the edit now. First rule is only internal forward, it will happen behind the scene so effectively it just pulls the content from correct directories.

Comment: Would it be the rule if `example.com/about/js/something.js` 404s? (file is in `example.com/js/something.js`)